# Multiple cursors has undefined variables

Tags: variables, multiple-cursors, warning

I installed [multiple cursors mode](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el#mark-one-more-occurrence).  My init.el has the following at the bottom:

```
(require 'bytecomp)
(require 'multiple-cursors)
(multiple-cursors-mode 1)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-c C-S-c") 'mc/edit-lines)
(global-set-key (kbd "C->") 'mc/mark-next-like-this)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<") 'mc/mark-previous-like-this)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-<") 'mc/mark-all-like-this)
```

However, every time I open emacs, I see the following:

```
Warning (bytecomp): reference to free variable ‘multiple-cursors-mode’
Warning (bytecomp): reference to free variable ‘mc--read-char’
Warning (bytecomp): assignment to free variable ‘mc--read-char’
Warning (bytecomp): reference to free variable ‘multiple-cursors-mode’
Warning (bytecomp): reference to free variable ‘mc--read-quoted-char’
Warning (bytecomp): assignment to free variable ‘mc--read-quoted-char’
Warning (bytecomp): reference to free variable ‘rectangular-region-mode’
```

What did I forget to add?

Comment: Bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: You do not want to enable `multiple-cursors-mode` when Emacs loads.  Instead, the minor mode is automatically enabled when you use the keyboard shortcuts that you have defined and the mode is automatically exited when you press the enter key.  Thus, remove `(multiple-cursors-mode 1)` ...  However, that may not necessarily be the source of your bytecomp warnings ....

Comment: I didn't have this error before adding all 7 of those lines.